Measurable preimage of a set
Given the Borel algebra in $[0,1], \beta$ and the Lebesgue measure $m$, I have been asked to show that the function in $[0,1]^2,(x,t) \rightarrow \chi_{[x,1]}(t), f: [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable in the Borel product $\sigma$-algebra. I almost have the solution, but I don't know how to express the result as a union of borelians in the domain set. What I've done is the following:

For $f$ to be measurable, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, f^{-1}((a,\infty)) \in \beta \otimes\beta$. For $a > 1$, this set is the empty one, which is obviously a measurable set. When $a \leq 1$, the image only takes two possible values, $0,1$, so if $a \leq 1, f^{-1}((a,\infty)) = f^{-1}(\{0,1\})$. Here comes the problem, $f$ takes the value $1$ for intervals of the form $\{x\} \times [x,1]$, so the preimage would be the union on these intervals $\forall x \in [0,1]$. However, this union is uncountable. I don't know how to write these as a countable union of the product of borelians in $[0,1]$ (or intersections, or whatever). I know that the representation of this in a 2-dimensional plane would be half of the square $[0,1]^2$, in which the square is partitioned by its main diagonal. The square is of course measurable, but half of it I'm not sure (in theory, it has to be measurable because of what I'm required to show from the exercise itself). For $\{0\}$ is the same (the other half square). I would be grateful if somedoby could give me a hint.
